# How to pass an integer to a parameter through HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Am new to java and have a query.Please suggest me a solution :

Am doing API level testing and need to pass the request body parameters of a service like below :

Comment: can you use Map<String, Object> ?

Comment: Can't you just pass an integer to the parameter and then convert it to a string? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your integer value in string and then pass it, as your method expect String parameter, you cannot directly pass integer

```
sell.requestAdd( "Amount",String.valueOf(Your_Integer_Value));
```

Comment: in this case in JSON value will be string. It's same, as store just String `"1"`

Answer (score 0):

Java is strongly typed language, so your Map can't store Integer values, as String is defined as both key and value. If you want to store any object - changed map to `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class which holds string and int values. In other words, `HaspMap<String,Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create some kind of a class which will represent your map key/values so it will be easier to work with it for other developers.